# How I make a join execute only if a certain value is a number?

Tags: mysql

i've got this join sql code:

```
SELECT tracce.titolo, tracce.data, a1.aka as 'main', a2.aka as 'feat'
FROM tracce 
LEFT JOIN artist a1 ON tracce.idma = a1.id
LEFT JOIN feat ON feat.idt = tracce.id
LEFT JOIN artist a2 ON a2.id = feat.ida
```

Table structure is:

- artist: id - aka
- tracce: id - titolo - idma - data (id of track, titolo is title of the track, idma is the id of the main artist and data is date)
- feat: idt - ida (idt is the id of the track and ida is the id of the featured artist)

example of tables:

- Artist: 1 - Andrea / 2 - Antonio
- Tracce: 20 - Stacks - 1 - 09072020
- Feat: 20 - 2 / 20 - Simone

I want, after joining I will obtain:

- Titolo / Data / Main / Feat
- Stacks / 09072020 / Andrea / Antonio (where antonio is the aka of id = 2)
- Stacks / 09072020 / Andrea / Simone (where simone is the value of ida in feat table)

The field feat.ida is a string that contain an ID if the featured artist is in our sistem or the name of the artist if isn't in oure system. When I execute this query, when feat.ida isn't a number (so when there's a name), it returns 'Null' but i want that it returns the value of 'feat.ida'. Thanks a lot

Comment: Please add few rows of sample data and the expected result. The question is interesting, but it's not clear enough to answer. The join you want certainly can be done, The key aspect is: can you do it against a single table or a pre-computed table expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `COALESCE()` function to pick the first value that is not null.

```
SELECT tracce.titolo, tracce.data, a1.aka as 'main', COALESCE(a2.aka, feat.ida) as 'feat'
FROM tracce 
LEFT JOIN artist a1 ON tracce.idma = a1.id
LEFT JOIN feat ON feat.idt = tracce.id
LEFT JOIN artist a2 ON a2.id = feat.ida
```

This should give you result you are looking.

But your DB design is flawed and might lead to problems in future. You shouldn't store two different types of values in same field (id/name). For example what are you going to do, if you will have an artist that will use a number as their pseudonym. In situation like that you won't be able to say if the number is ID or name.
It will be much better to have extra column for artist's name when the artist doesn't have a record in your artist table.

Comment: Using an extra column is also a most easiest way... Can I do a join where the value of first column and the value of second column are given in the same field? To have the same result as now

Comment: @AndreaRiccio you can use same `COALESCE` as i posted in my answer. You only need to replace `feat.ida` with the field that contains the artist name in `feat` table.